# Unexpected Icon and background color for Android Wear notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I am working on an app that sends notifications using the NotificationManager. I set up an Android Wear emulator and have my android phone connected to the emulator. The notifications my app generates appear on the Android Wear emulator, but the icons and color used are not what I'd expect.

The notification uses 1 of 3 icons as the notification icon, and sets a different LED color for each of the 3 cases. The notification I see on the watch emulator uses the app icon, and not the icon I set in the notification. Also, the background color of the notification is a solid red background, and I'm not sure what's setting it that color.

How can I get my notifications on the watch to match the icon of the notification I set, and how can I change the BG Color?!

Below, the Pink box is the application icon (and not the notification icon I'd expect).

[Watch Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtz8L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know the colors of the LED are irrelevant for wearable notifications. The background color is selected by default the icon and its priotity, if you set a big icon image it will use this. Since the quality of that big icon image meight be bad there is another call to achieve that. Here is a full example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("message")
        // replace the drawable if you want something else
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender =
                                    new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                         R.drawable.background);
// in the line above you can change the background image
extender.setBackground(bg);
builder.extend(extender);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                          NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(42, builder.build());
```

Comment: I don't understand why the notification icon on the watch is the app icon, and not the icon I use as the notification icon that shows on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

The notification icons come from the res/drawable folders of the handheld app.  Do you have an icon with the same name in the res/drawable-hdpi folder?

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

Note: The bitmap that you use with setBackground() should have a resolution of 400x400 for non-scrolling backgrounds and 640x400 for backgrounds that support parallax scrolling. Place these bitmap images in the res/drawable-nodpi directory of your handheld app. Place other non-bitmap resources for wearable notifications, such as those used with the setContentIcon() method, in the res/drawable-hdpi directory of your handheld app.